# nested_form gem doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rubygems, nested

i have tried to use raynb nested_form gem but somehow it doesn't work

here is the github depository:
https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#non-asset-pipeline-setup

i installed the gem with bundle insall.

the problems are :
1) it says that you should insert:
//= require jquery_nested_form
in the application.js file so the installed js file will work.
it doesn't - so i installed it by myself and put it in the js directory.

2) basically the gem doesn't work after I insatlled it...

here is my view file :

```
<%= form_for(:feast, :url=>{:action=>'create'}) do |f|%>
   <%= f.label("feast time", :feast_time)%><br /><br />
   <%= f.datetime_select(:feast_time, :order => [:day, :month ,:year]) %>
<br /><br />


<%= f.label("feast place", :feast_place)%><br /><br />
<%= f.text_field(:feast_place) %> <br /><br />

#this part is irrelevent to the question --------------------------------------------


<h2>participants

<u>
    <%= link_to '#', :onclick => "add_par(); return false;",class: "right" do %>
  <%= image_tag('add_participants.png', :size => '100x100', :alt => 'Photo    
       Gallery') %>
     <%end%>
    </u>
    </h2>   

    <br /><br /><br />   

<div id ="par">

</div>      
 ##  end of irrelevant block-----------------------------------------------
```

here is the code relevant block :

```
<%= f.fields_for :participations do |fp| %>
  <%= fp.text_field :user_id %>
  <%= fp.link_to_remove "Remove this user" %>
<% end %>
<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a user", :participations %></p>

<%= submit_tag("start the feast") %>
```

basically saying it doesn't work ....
why ? is bundle install not enough to install a gem? is there other good gems to add a 
nested field by a link and remove by a link?

Comment: can you list the steps you did to install it?

Comment: yeah: i add - gem 'nested_form' to my gem file and then run bundle install

Comment: did you add `//= require jquery_nested_form` in your application.js file?

Comment: yes i added this line: //= require jquery_nested_form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here it goes: i tried 2 plugins and they didn't work so i figured that i am doing something wrong with the general form.

i used matched routes . as i changed to REST routes everything works fine.

probebly the previous form decleration line :

{:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
was lacking the @feast variable so it can append to it the nested parts. so maybe there is a way to fix it even with matched routes maybe something like:

     {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

but since i change to REST routes its working and i don't bother to check.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at [nested_form repo](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#non-asset-pipeline-setup) and it says

`Use the nested_form_for helper method to enable the nesting.
<%= nested_form_for @project do |f| %>`

and you are using rails `form_for helper`. You should have something like this:

```
<%= nested_form_for @feast do |f| %> #assuming you have @feast = Feast.new in your new action
```

Also **rails 4 ships with accepts nested attribute feature** so if you are using this gem for that feature only then there's no need for it.

Comment: thanks . i did it but it didn't work... weird as if the gem is not installed at all  - yet it is

Comment: when you used `<%= nested_form_for @feast do |f| %>` did you get any error?